# Converting arrays between NumPy and JPype?

Tags: java, python, numpy

Does a library or script exist to convert between [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) and [JPype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/) arrays?

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't

```
JArray(float, 1)(numpyarray)
```

work?

At least

```
JArray(float, 1)(numpyarray.tolist())
```

should work.

Comment: thanks. i'm working on site library to automate jpype->numpy and numpy->jpype conversions. is there something like this already ? 
And also , how stable is jpype from your exeprience ?

Comment: sorry i just jpype once tested it once, so i dont have much experience in it. 
the one in line above is the dimension of the array, so may replace it with numpyarray.ndim().